# How to stop the ringtone of alarm?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, ringtone

> Hello everyone, I am doing a alarm application. Here is my removeAlarm and AlarmReceiver. I set a ringtone for my alarm. But when this time gone, the ringtone turned on and I wait 1 minute, 2 minute but it didn't turn off. So, what can I do to turn off it?

```
public static void removeAlarm(Context context, long id){
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) id, myIntent, 0);
    if(alarmManager != null)
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Ringtone ringtone = null;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
    ringtone.play();
    Intent x = new Intent(context,AlarmDialog.class);
    context.startActivity(x);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried ringtone.stop(); ?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel your ringtone after a delay, you can add a `Handler` task to your `BroadcastReceiver` like this, after `ringtone.play()`:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    ringtone.stop();
  }
}, 1000 * 60); // runs stop() after 1 minute
```